# Kendo MVC TreeView not rendering ".k-in" items correctly

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

We're using Kendo UI MVC 2019.2.619 in our MVC5 project.

Our TreeView is rendering like this:

[image]

We took a look at the HTML it's generating at our end

[image]

But it should look like this

[image]

(Source: https://www.telerik.com/forums/k--items)

This is how we generate our TreeView.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                                  .Name("BroadcastTreeView")
                                  .DataTextField("Text")
                                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                      .Model(model => model
                                          .Id("Id")
                                          .HasChildren("HasChildren")
                                          .Children("Items"))
                                      .Read(read => read.Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Action("ReadTree", "Broadcast").Data("treeViewReadData"))
                                      .Events(events => events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd")))
                                  .Messages(msg => msg
                                      .Loading("Data ophalen...")
                                      .RequestFailed("Kan data niet ophalen")
                                      .Retry("Probeer opnieuw"))
                                  .Events(events => events
                                      .Change("onTreeViewChange")
                                      .Expand("onTreeViewExpand"))
                                  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "custom-border" }))
```

When we drag the .k-in span outside of the .k-icon span in the Chrome debugger. The layout is like it's supposed to be. We do not have any custom JavaScript that's manipulating the TreeView. Is this a known bug with version we're using? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that the Kendo css files and js files are being included properly and match the version of the wrappers you're using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We've searched for a couple of hours, but no luck. We made the decision to upgrade to Kendo 2020.5.513. It makes for some layout issues but it has fixed the issue with the treeview.

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded your jQuery to 3.5 recently? It doesn't allow for some self-closing tags, like `<span class="k-icon" />` which are present in Kendo's source.

See https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/5735 .

You need to upgrade Kendo or downgrade jQuery .

Comment: We upgraded Kendo last week, this fixed the issue. Thank you either way.

Comment: @StephanBisschop happy to help. Please mark as accepted the answer that you think will best help future StackOverflow users who will encounter the same problem.